# How do you check for nullable value in an if statement

Tags: c#, nullable

I have the following code:

```
string thing="";
if(request.Session.Attributes?.TryGetValue("varName", out thing))
{
  //do stuff
}
```

request.Session.Attributes is a dictionary.

I understand that you **can't** have `if(bool?)` which is what the above does.
I also know that you **can** have .GetValueOrDefault() so that null will be treated as false.
But I can't do `request.Session.Attributes?.GetValueOrDefault().TryGetValue("varName", out thing)`
So what is the correct way to return `false` if Attributes is `null` otherwise return the `bool` from the TryGetValue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick and slightly dirty way is doing:

```
string thing="";
if(request.Session.Attributes?.TryGetValue("varName", out thing) ?? false)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

In this way you are sure that if `Attributes` is null, the second branch of the `??` will be chosen and it will not get inside the if.

Personally, I would split it, as having it in a 1-liner does not improve the code that much. It'd become:

```
string thing="";
var attributes = request.Session.Attributes; 
if(attributes != null && attributes.TryGetValue("varName", out thing))
{
  //do stuff
}
```

This is much more readable. Sometimes it is just fair to avoid using new features of the language if they do not improve the code.

Bonus tip:
You can get a line back removing the declaration of `things` and placing it just after the `out` :
`attributes.TryGetValue("varName", out string thing)`

Comment: I disagree with the *"dirty"*. To me, it's clean

Comment: @Cid it is a matter of taste, I guess. Putting a naked `false` inside an `if` smells to me. It feels like you are not using the language as you should. I would rather assign the nullable object to a variable and check that (see alternative solution).

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you're looking for:

```cs
if (request.Session.Attributes?.TryGetValue("varName", out thing) == true)
```

Alternatively:

```cs
if (request.Session.Attributes?.TryGetValue("varName", out thing) ?? false)
```

The null-coalescing `??` operator here is effectively saying "If we didn't call `TryGetValue` because `Attributes` is null, this is what I want to pretend it returned."

Answer (score 3):

to set a default value of an nullable type in c# you can use the ?? opperator

```
if(nullableboolean ?? false){
}
```

so that would default to false

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Dictionary<string,string> stuff = null;
if(stuff?.TryGetValue("key",out string val) ?? false){
        
   Console.WriteLine("hey");
        
}
```